# Paint onMeasure() decide height width

Tags: java, android

all

I am facing strange issue here, and I need expert advise on that.

I have a **customview** which is drawing a points and text along side it .
Now my problem is that, i dont know its height of width at it will be count in `onDraw` method.(dynamic calculation of course). So how to do handle 
`setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight)` in this scenario. you do not know height and width, it will be calculated in `onDraw` depends on **text length** please help.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is use [Paint.getTextWidths()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextWidths(java.lang.String, float[])) in your onMeasure().

You'll get widths of all characters, so in a loop just add all the widths

```
float textWidth = 0;
float [] charsWidth = new float[text.length()];

int widths = mPaint.getTextWidths(text, charsWidth);

for (int i = 0; i < widths; i++) {
    textWidth += charsWidth[i];
}
```

and you have width of the text.

Don't forget to initialize the `Paint` object with the correct parameters, especially text size beforehand.

**EDIT :** if you need both text width and height then use instead [Paint.getTextBounds()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29).

Comment: I do use `StaticLayout` for the texts so it will be height and width both to be measured, which i dont know how to do inside `onMeasure`..

Comment: please check `StaticLayout` first it is multiline texts here and a image like `leftdrawable` in it also. so this is not that easy bro.